# ?url= does not work

Tags: php

I am coding for a site which use admin panel and member panel both panels files are located in two separate folders named master and member. Both have main.php file which are header files from those files i redirect to other files, Both main.php use same function file to redirect url by   ?url= .
Now problem is admin  main.php redirect to correct url  but  member main.php returns back without showing errors.

function.php is

```
    <?php
    function logout($destinationPath)
    {
        if(count($_SESSION))
        {
            foreach($_SESSION AS $key=>$value)
            {
                session_unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            }
            session_destroy();
        }
        echo "<script language='javaScript' type='text/javascript'>
                window.location.href='".$destinationPath."';
            </script>";
    }
    function validation_check($checkingVariable, $destinationPath)
    {
        if($checkingVariable == '')
        {
            echo "<script language='javaScript' type='text/javascript'>
                window.location.href='".$destinationPath."';
            </script>";
        }
    }
    function realStrip($input)
    {
        return mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($input)));
    }
    function no_of_record($table, $cond)
    {
        $sql    = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$cond;
        $qry    = mysql_query($sql);
        $rec    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
        $count  = $rec['CNT'];
        return $count;
    }
    //drop down
    function drop_down($required=null, $text_field, $table_name, $id, $name, $cond, $selected_id=null)
    {
        $qry = mysql_query("SELECT $id, $name FROM $table_name WHERE $cond ORDER BY $name ASC");
        $var = '';
        if(mysql_num_rows($qry)>0)
        {
            $var = '<select id="'.$text_field.'" name="'.$text_field.'" '.$required.'>';
            $var .='<option value="">--Choose--</option>';
            while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
            {
                $selected = '';
                if($selected_id==$r[$id]){
                    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                }
                $var .='<option value="'.$r[$id].'" '.$selected.'>'.$r[$name].'</option>';
            }
            $var .='</select>';
        }
        echo $var;
    }
    function uploadResume($title,$uploaddoc,$txtpropimg)
    {
        $upload= $uploaddoc;
        $filename=$_FILES[$txtpropimg]['name'];
        $fileextension=strchr($filename,".");
        $photoid=rand();
        $newfilename=$title.$photoid.$fileextension;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$txtpropimg]['tmp_name'],$upload.$newfilename);
        return $newfilename;
    }



    function fRecord($field, $table, $cond)
    {
        $fr = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM $table WHERE $cond"));
        return $fr[$field];
    }


    function get_values_for_keys($mapping, $keys) {
      $output_arr = '';
      $karr = explode(',',$keys);
      foreach($karr as $key) {
       $output_arr .= $mapping[$key].', ';
      }
      $output_arr = rtrim($output_arr, ', ');
      return $output_arr;
    }

    function getBaseURL() {
    $isHttps = ((array_key_exists('HTTPS', $_SERVER) 
            && $_SERVER['HTTPS']) ||
        (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', $_SERVER) 
                && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    );
    return 'http' . ($isHttps ? 's' : '') .'://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}


    function request_uri()
    {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // IIS with ISAPI_REWRITE
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'])
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
    $p = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
    $p .= '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    return $p;
    }
    preg_match ('`/'.FOLDER_NAME.'(.*)(.*)$`', request_uri(), $matches);
    $tableType = (!empty ($matches[1]) ? ($matches[1]) : '');
    $url_array=explode('/',$tableType);


?>
```

In main.php

```
<li><a href='?url=epin/used.php'><span>Used e-Pin</span></a></li>
```

is used to redirect url

http://localhost/abcd.biz/secure/master/main.php?url=epin/used.php is working
 and   http://localhost/abcd.biz/secure/member/main.php?url=epin/used.php is not working

Both main.php files are using same function file so I can't get the reason please help to get out of it, thanks in advance, try to clarify it also.
I am not using any htaccess file

Comment: *"without showing errors."* - are you checking for them? Is your system setup to catch/log/display? If not, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: function.php looks incomplete.

Comment: *"and `http://localhost/abcd.biz/secure/member/main.php?url=epin/used.php` is not working"* - since you're probably trying to access through an SSL socket, then you should be using `https://localhost/abcd.biz/secure/member/main.php?url=epin/used.php`, n'est-ce pas? Unless this is a redirection problem.

Comment: @Fred -ii  it doesnt yields  it is already included in cinfig file

Comment: @maxhb  sir now function.php  is  compleate check it please

Comment: @ Fred -ii   sir  admin url is  working in master dir with http

Comment: Please read [ask] and keep in the question only the code that is relevant to the problem you encounter.

Comment: @axiac  sir  maxhb asked for comlete file  function.php  so i have posted it, please read the lower part of this file and sugest me what to do with function.php file or main.php file